# How to convert JAVA program to PHP to carryout RSA encryption

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa, public-key

I am trying to implement AEPS API but unable to encrypt aadhar number in php. In developer guide they provided method to encrypt using JAVA and i am using php.
Given JAVA code is as follows.

```
public static String calculateRSA( String salt ) throws InvalidKeyException, Exception {

Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPublicKey());
byte[] secretMessageBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessageBytes);
String encodedMessage = Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedMessageBytes);
return encodedMessage;
}
public static PublicKey getPublicKey() throws Exception {
String rawPublicKey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCaFyrzeDhMaFLx+LZUNOOO14Pj9aPfr+1WOanDgDHxo9NekENYcWUftM9Y17ul2pXr3bqw0GCh4uxNoTQ5cTH4buI42LI8ibMaf7Kppq9MzdzI9/7pOffgdSn+P8J64CJAk3VrVswVgfy8lABt7fL8R6XReI9x8ewwKHhCRTwBgQIDAQAB";
byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(rawPublicKey);
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
return kf.generatePublic(spec);// generatePrivate(spec);
}
```

I tried

```
$publicKey = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCaFyrzeDhMaFLx+LZUNOOO14Pj9aPfr+1WOanDgDHxo9NekENYcWUftM9Y17ul2pXr3bqw0GCh4uxNoTQ5cTH4buI42LI8ibMaf7Kppq9MzdzI9/7pOffgdSn+P8J64CJAk3VrVswVgfy8lABt7fL8R6XReI9x8ewwKHhCRTwBgQIDAQAB';

include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($publicKey); // public key

$plaintext = '828409353766';

//$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
$encrypted = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);

$encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);
```

Comment: What does "unable to" mean, exactly? What have you tried? What specifically is your issue? Please show the PHP code you have written so far. See also the [tour], [ask] and how to create a [mre]  for more guidance on how to approach asking a question here. Thanks.

Comment: Reference link [link](https://developers.eko.in/reference#aeps-api)

Comment: If you have further information, please edit your question to include it so it's clearly visible, don't add it to the comments. Thanks. (The "edit" button is right there at the end of the question, under the blue tags)

Comment: added php script i tried

Comment: This link could be helpful for you (disclaimer: I'm the author): https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/tree/main/RsaEncryptionPkcs15String. I'm using openssl as security provider.